# User interface of a simple single image detail view

Tags: layout, image

I know this sounds generic, but I'm trying to find some clues and examples.

What would be the best way to present a single image (about 1/4 of desktop screen size), along with some info (name and description)? Centered or left aligned? Where the name and description should go? It should work also for mobile.

**EDIT:** To make it more specific, it is a detail view for a user posted product with a photo, title and description. The most important content is the image and title. The description is secondary (and is optional). There are no any other instances of this view. And the only user input is a link to download the mobile app.

**EDIT2:** This is how it looks currently. Need to improve to make it more usable and appealing.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This question requires that you answer a few things to give you the correct solution. First, what is the man the most important content on the page, the image, text, what? Second, considering what the most important content is, is it viewable on both desktop and mobile with little to no user input? Because it should be the easiest to reach/view.

Third, are there any instances where the more important content isn't more important, or perhaps where a gallery or additional space is required? Do those instances interfere with the overall layout you have planned? If so, do those cases require an entire change or just a different way of displaying content?

Ultimately there's no right way to display content, only a right way for you and your users. So when you work on this layout problem, consider the questions above and what will deliver the simplest experience for your users. Feel free to give additional specifics here and we can talk more in depth about it.